# Jquery autocomplete not display result box

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have this js script :

```
$('#other_teacher').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app_dev.php/en/teacher/ajax/courseadd-teacher/'+request.term,
            type: 'GET',
            dataatType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                response($.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    return {
                        label: value,
                        value: index
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

And the result of ajax request is :

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Moran bob"},{"id":2,"name":"Willam Lawsan"}]
```

Ajax resquest start, data have the result object, but result window is not displayed.

Comment: Could you post your html too please

Comment: put this css  http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css and try using ur code or mine

Comment: any luck? It's good practice to keep us notified of your progess

Comment: i will try to night i'm at school a this time but i have already css in my head section

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.map` instead of `$.each` and then access the value of the fields from the object.
I also added a select function and a logger inside to confirm check if you're actually getting anything

```
$('#other_teacher').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app_dev.php/en/teacher/ajax/courseadd-teacher/'+request.term,
            type: 'GET',
            dataatType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.id, // or item.name if you want
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put Css for autocomplete and then try this code

```
   $('#textbox id').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("url?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
                response(data);

            });

        },
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 100

    });
```